# How to load dropdown using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

**load dropdown ,when i am adding data in city table at that time below dropdown will load on page without page load**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onchange="showhideDiv()" 
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"></asp:DropDownList>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [City]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnAddCity').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '2tabledataenterusing1page.aspx/insert_data',
            data: "{'Name':'" + document.getElementById('txtaddcity').value + "'}",

            success: function (response) {
                $('#txtaddcity').val('');
                $('#MainContent_DropDownList1').Onload();
                alert("Record Has been Saved in Database");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('there is some error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error #1**

You don't want to use `.click()` as the event, because `click` fires *immediately* when the user clicks on the drop-down, long before they choose a new value.

Use [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

---

**Error #2**

This is wrong:

```
data: "{'Name':'" + document.getElementById('txtaddcity').value + "'}"
```

It produces the following string:

```
{'Name':'some city name'}
```

and that's not JSON. There are no single-quoted strings in JSON, trying to parse this on the server side will fail.

**Don't build JSON by string concatenation.** Ever. Always use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
data: JSON.stringify({Name: document.getElementById('txtaddcity').value}),
```

This will create valid JSON from a JS object, and the server will be able to parse it successfully.